# Unfortunately, the calculator has stopped.

Tags: android

I am not getting any errors in eclipse. (this is only a partial app, i have coded for the first "add" button function only.) please help out here, because my app is crashing after inputing the values and clicking  the add button.
here is my code:-

```
package ajay.calculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   EditText box1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.box_1);
   EditText box2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.box_2);




}




public void addNumbers(EditText box1,EditText box2){

 double a,b; 

 String str,str2 = new String();     
 str = box1.getText().toString();
 str2 = box2.getText().toString();
 a = Double.parseDouble(str);
 b = Double.parseDouble(str2);

 Log.d(box1.getText().toString(),"TAG");
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,Result.class);
 intent1.putExtra("first_number", a);
 intent1.putExtra("second number", b);
 startActivity(intent1);

}

public void multiplyNumbers(EditText box1,EditText box2){

 double a,b; 

 String str,str2 = new String();     
 str = box1.getText().toString();
 str2 = box2.getText().toString();
 a = Double.parseDouble(str);
 b = Double.parseDouble(str2);
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,Result.class);
 intent1.putExtra("first_number", a);
 intent1.putExtra("second number", b);
 startActivity(intent1);

}

public void subtractNumbers(EditText box1,EditText box2){

 double a,b; 

 String str,str2 = new String();     
 str = box1.getText().toString();
 str2 = box2.getText().toString();
 a = Double.parseDouble(str);
 b = Double.parseDouble(str2);
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,Result.class);
 intent1.putExtra("first_number", a);
 intent1.putExtra("second number", b);
 startActivity(intent1);
}

public void divideNumbers(EditText box1,EditText box2){

 double a,b; 

 String str,str2 = new String();     
 str = box1.getText().toString();
 str2 = box2.getText().toString();
 a = Double.parseDouble(str);
 b = Double.parseDouble(str2);
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,Result.class);
 intent1.putExtra("first_number", a);
 intent1.putExtra("second number", b);
 startActivity(intent1);
}









}


and the second activity is as follows:-


package ajay.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class Result extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent1 = getIntent();
    double x = intent1.getDoubleExtra("first_number", 0.0);
    double y = intent1.getDoubleExtra("second number", 0.0);
    TextView tview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    tview.setText("The result is " + x+y);
    setContentView(tview);

}
}
```

My xml files:-

1) Main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/box_1"
    android:hint="@string/enter_no"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
    >


</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/box_2"
    android:hint="@string/enter_no"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/box_1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" 

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/box_2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/box_2"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:text="@string/func_add"
    android:onClick="addNumbers" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/box_2"
    android:text="@string/func_mult"
    android:onClick="multiplyNumbers" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:text="@string/func_divide"
    android:onClick="divideNumbers" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:text="@string/func_subtract" 
    android:onClick="subtractNumbers"/>

 <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/text1"
     android:hint="@string/result"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"


     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2) the xml for 2nd activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".Result" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What error are you getting on logCat?

Comment: Please post only *relevant* code once you have tried narrowing down the problem. Also check logcat you probably are getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. button can pass parameter  to addNumbers beacause didnt' know what pass.
2. at first you may call setConetView and then findViewById.

   TextView tview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
   tview.setText("The result is " + x+y);
   setContentView(tview);
3. Read more about the basics of an android development

Comment: thanks! its my first program so you will have to excuse the petty errors.